# Issue getting proper exception from PostgreSQL in c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, exception, npgsql

I use Npgsql.dll ver. 2.2.2.0 as Data provider in my C# application and when I perform insert/update/delete operation that causes constraint violation provider raises "42601 syntax error" instead of proper exception.

The same situation is with custom exceptions from PostgreSQL functions.

However divide by zero exception is properly re-thrown by Npgsql.

How do I change such an odd behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue resolved by downgrading to Npgsql.dll ver. 1.3.
Unfortunately it's not the proper solution, but it works fine at least.